# Removing specific rows in Panda with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have below sample in a csv file. I want to check below rule:

1- First of all check all the parents which have "-" dash in the name then:

2- If *df["Parent"]* that we searched (rule1) in all CSV file is like *df["Child"]* :
for this sample *Saher-1* is *Parent* in row1 and also *Child* in row2 and also for that specific case if the *df["Child"]* is like *df["Parent"]*,I want to remove the Child row. here *Mori* is *Child* in the row1 one and also *Parent* in row2.

I don't know how to use if clause  in this sample.

I have below file:

```
Parent      Child
Saher-1      Mori
Mori        Saher-1
John        Jake
Saher-2     Mary
```

My expectation:

```
Parent        Child
Saher-1       Mori
John          Jake
Saher-2       Mary
```

Comment: This list is ambiguous, because how can we be sure that Saher is the Parent and not Mori just by looking at the list? Just because it was defined first? But what if it is not in order?

Comment: You are right Marcos. The first checking is about the name. first we should have a look at Parent and see if any "-" exists in the Parent, then check in all the csv file if that Parent which we find exist in child. the child row must be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Parent':['Saher-1','Mori','John','Saher-2'],
    'Child':['Mori','Saher-1','Jake','Mary']
})
# print(df)
  Parent    Child
0  Saher-1     Mori
1     Mori  Saher-1
2     John     Jake
3  Saher-2     Mary

#check rows where parent-child have same names
df_dup = df[df['Child'].isin(df['Parent'].tolist())]
print(df_dup)
 Parent    Child
0  Saher-1     Mori
1     Mori  Saher-1

#remove them from main DF
df=pd.concat([df,df_dup]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
print(df)
   Parent Child
2     John  Jake
3  Saher-2  Mary

#leave only parent with '-' in dubplaceted df
df_dup = df_dup[df_dup['Parent'].str.contains('-')]
print(df_dup)
Parent Child
0  Saher-1  Mori

#create final df
df=pd.concat([df,df_dup]).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
0     John  Jake
1  Saher-2  Mary
2  Saher-1  Mori
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try left `merge` with optional parameter `indicator=True` to identify rows which satisfy the specified rules:

```
m = df['Parent'].str.contains('-')
d = df.merge(df[m], left_on=['Parent', 'Child'], right_on=['Child', 'Parent'], how='left', indicator=True)
d = df[d['_merge'].eq('left_only')]
```

---

```
print(d)
    Parent Child
0  Saher-1  Mori
2     John  Jake
3  Saher-2  Mary
```

Comment: @SaraDaniel Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

This answer requires that the Parent will always be marked with a "-" or another marker, otherwise it becomes ambiguous who is the Parent element and who is the Child. Someone else might be able to give a better answer.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Parent": ["Saher-1", "Mori", "John"], "Child": ["Mori", "Saher-1", "Jake"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# This checks for Parents with dashes on the Child column
df_temp = df[df["Child"].str.contains("-")] 

# This use concat to join both dataframes, removing duplicates
# Essentially, it removes the df_temp from df
df = pd.concat([df, df_temp]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

print(df)
>>>    Parent Child
>>> 0  Saher-1  Mori
>>> 2  John  Jake
```

Comment: Thanks but there is a issue: If only Saher-1 is the parent and hasn't been repeated as a child in other row. It will be ignored. I saved the result of your code in a csv file and now I see all the Parent which include the first rule but doesn't include the second rule has been removed. So i just update my example.